# composer dropping 2nd slash after https: in url

Tags: php, composer-php

php Composer was working fine and then I updated and now I get this message with nothing else changed. Notice the 2nd backslash in https:\ is missing.

Failed: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 0: The "https:\xxx.xxxxxx.com/repos/release-belt/releases/Key-Words-1.00.zip" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

the packages.json file did not change and has https:\xxx.xxxxx.com. I'm using Slim to handle the download on the server

Comment: That's not a valid url. It should be `https://` which is why it's trying to find a local file instead of a URL.

Comment: I'm stupid - the funny thing it was working until the update